# Detect from bundled code that it was compiled in development mode

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

There is `process.env.NODE_ENV==='development'` but that's defined on server side which runs webpack or its dev-server. I need to determine it from the bundled code which runs in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) in the building process to define a global variable like this:

```
//
const mode = "production"

module.exports = {
    mode: mode,
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __mode__: JSON.stringify(mode)
        })
    ]
}
```

Then you can access `__mode__`.

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of it; expected there's more simple way

Comment: @AlexeyBerezkin What's not simple about it?

Comment: I suppose the problem is that DefinePlugin does just a simple string replace and does it in all source (and even probably resource) files, which might have a lot of side effects.